# Is there any way to update the version of mermaid used by pyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, markdown, mermaid

Is there any way to update the version of mermaid used by pyCharm?

Motivation:
I want to use `tickinterval` for Gantt chart so I need v9.3.0 but PyCharm installs version 8.14.0

Environment:
OS: MacOS Ventura Version 13.1
PyCharm: 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)

== Edited ==
I updated PyCharm to 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) and got mermaid version 9.1.3
but I haven't solved the problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PyCharm 2022.3.3 CE you can now go to to Settings --> Plugins --> Search 'mermaid' and click the "Install" button for version 10.